# ModelAdmin with a has_many relationship

Tags: php, silverstripe, modeladmin

I'm extending `ModelAdmin` to manage a `DataObject` and I have a `$has_many` relationship that is managed by another `DataObject`. I'd like to manage this object on another tab but am lost as to how I'd add it. My basic code:

ApplicationAdmin.php:

```
class Applications extends ModelAdmin {
    private static $menu_title = 'Applications';

    private static $url_segment = 'apps';

    private static $managed_models = array (
        'Application'
    );
}
```

Application.php

```
class Application extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(
        'Name' => "varchar"
    );

    private static $has_many = array(
        'Documents' => 'Document',
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = FieldList::create(
            TextField::create('Name'),
        );

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Document.php

```
class Document extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(
        'Title' => "varchar",
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        "Document" => "File",
        "Application" => "Application"
    );

    public function getCMSFields () {
        $fields = FieldList::create(
            TextField::create('Title'),
            $doc = new UploadField('Document')
        );
        $doc->getValidator()->setAllowedExtensions(array('pdf', 'docx'));

        return $fields;
    }   
}
```

Basically I'd like to manage the documents for this entry under `Root.Documents` tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `GridField` to handle the relation between `Application` and `Document`, and place that field on its own tab if you wish. Example:

```
# Application.php
public function getCMSFields() {

    $fields         = parent::getCMSFields();
    $nameField      = TextField::create('Name');
    $documentsField = GridField::create(
        'Documents',
        'Documents',
        $this->Documents(),
        GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create()
    );

    $fields->addFieldToTab(
        'Root.Main',
        $nameField
    );

    $fields->addFieldToTab(
        'Root.Documents',
        $documentsField
    );

    return $fields;

}
```

Your code contains a some typos in the `Document` class (the classname has .php in it, `getValidator` should be `getValidator()`), and that class also needs a `$has_one = ['Application' => 'Application'];` for the relation to work.

Comment: Thanks. I'm curious, if I don't have the `addFieldToTab` for the `Root.Main` my fields still appear. Is this because the parent is creating default ones?

Comment: @Rudiger exactly, you can check out `getCMSFields()` in DataObject.php and follow the trace from there to where the fields are automatically generated. It's good practice to use `$fields = parent::getCMSFields();` because it has an extension hook in it which allows modules to modify all `DataObjects`' cms fields.